# Cypress API testing. Can not find property

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, web-api-testing

I am developing Cypress tests for my API.
The response from my API in Postman is below:

```js
{"infected" : false}
```

And my Cypress test is below:

```js
describe("Testing the result after scanning file", () => {
  it("Scan file", function () {
    //Declarations
    const fileName = 'example.json';
    cy.fixture(fileName, 'binary')
    .then((file) => Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(file))
    .then((blob) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", blob, fileName);
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData,
        url: '/scan'
      }).then(response => {
        console.log('the response is: ', response.body)       
        expect(response.body).to.have.property('infected').and.eq(false);
      });
    })
  });
});
```

In my browser, the Cypress test fails with the message:

```
assert expected {} to have property infected
```

I really have already broken my brain with this issue and still have no clue how to tackle it. Can anybody give me an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: The issue seems to be that your API is returning an empty object instead of your expected response. Is there anything from your postman call that you are missing in your `cy.request()`?

Comment: No, I have the response in postman and it is not an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

Try converting the response to json, you may be seeing a string version of the data.

Postman output will not be helpful, it could be converting automatically in the background.

```js
cy.request({
  ...
})

.then(response => response.json())
// OR
// .then(response => response.body.json())

.then(data => {

  console.log('the data is: ', data)               // better debug tool than Postman

  expect(data).to.have.property('infected').and.eq(false);
});
```

Comment: It still does not work. I face TypeError: responce.body.json - is not a function.

Comment: That's too bad - you should be able to debug, if you have a mind to.

Comment: That is another poblem - I can not debug cypress, and I even do not know how to watch the console. Standard developer tools do not show the console logs.

Comment: It's really simple, cannot see why you are unable.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it. I really have an empty response body: { }. I can not get why.

Comment: Next check response itself - maybe the property is directly on it, not on response.body.

Comment: I finally figured out what is wrong. The request body was stored as ArrayBuffer. I will add my answer below.